# Using residue theorem separately for real and imaginary parts

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate an integral with respect to a complex value. I just want to know if I can estimate the integral using the residue theorem separately for the real and imaginary parts of the mentioned value or I cannot at all use this method here.

Answer (score 4):

The real or imaginary part on their own aren't analytic and so you can't apply results for which they are required to be analytic separately to the two.

Comment: tnx for the answer....but what should i do in order to solve such a integral using residuen?

Comment: Identify the poles within the given curve and the corresponding residues (=coefficients of $(z-a_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent series).

Comment: can you please give me an example for a contour when the pole is in the form of a+b*i?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{\pi dz}{z - 0.5 i} = \pi$$